# Issue in sending data in fields in internet explorer

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-11

I am automating a form using selenium in Internet Explorer 11. There is a field which accepts 5 characters max. When I try to enter 2 characters the cursor still shows in that field and enter data of other field and no error shows for this. It is working fine in other browsers.

E.g Field 1 (max accept 5)   e.g sendkeys(12)
field 2       e.g sendkeys(456)

When I run code in field 1 it insert 12456 and insert nothing in next field.

Comment: I tried to make a test with this sample code on my side and looks like code is working fine on IE. https://textuploader.com/19wyz Can you please try to make a test with this sample code? If issue persist than try to provide your sample code. We will try to make a test with it to check the issue with your code.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, i have rectified the issue using robot class and using tab keystroke.

Comment: From your last comment, it looks like you had found the cause for the issue. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer for this issue and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.